# InfluxDB write operation stops working automatically after 24 hour/one day

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, influxdb

I am writing into InfluxDB using Java and what i am doing is using infinite loop to write points into DB as shown below.

```
while (true) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

    list.add("cpu,atag=test" + i + " idle=100,usertime=10,system=1");

    }

            influxDB.write(dbName, "autogen", InfluxDB.ConsistencyLevel.ALL, list);
            list.clear();
            logger.info("WritePoints for " + 1 + " writes of " + 100000 + " Points took:" + watch);
    }
```

I keep running this program for longer period of time to check and see how disk compression and disk writing speed is doing, but after 24 hours or after 1 day i am getting "time out" exception as shown below.

How can i keep running same program for like couple of days. I can catch exception and create connection again but is there any other way of doing it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: timeout
    at retrofit.RetrofitError.networkError(RetrofitError.java:27)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
    at org.influxdb.impl.$Proxy0.writePoints(Unknown Source)
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.write(InfluxDBImpl.java:159)
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.write(InfluxDBImpl.java:171)
    at net.company.influx.InfluxDBBatchWriter.doParse(InfluxDBBatchWriter.java:61)
    at net.company.influx.InfluxDBBatchWriter.main(InfluxDBBatchWriter.java:25)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:87)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:722)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:576)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
    at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:190)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?

Comment: version is v1.0.2.

Comment: It looks like you're writing batches of 100k points, which is definitely suboptimal. Try dropping you batch size down to 5-10k and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @MichaelDesa How to drop the batch size down to 5-10k ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxDB will perform sub-optimally with very large batch sizes. Try modifying your test to something like

```
int n = 0;
int numSeries = 100000;
int batchSize = 5000;

while (true) {

  for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    n = (n + 1) % numSeries
    list.add("cpu,atag=test" + n + " idle=100,usertime=10,system=1");
  }

  influxDB.write(dbName, "autogen", InfluxDB.ConsistencyLevel.ALL, list);
  list.clear();
  logger.info("WritePoints for " + 1 + " writes of " + 5000 + " Points took:" + watch);
}
```